# NestJS UDP Server without HTTP

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Is there any way to use nestjs as standalone udp server? I created custom udp server adapter as explained in documents but when i try to star application i gives me this error.

*No driver (HTTP) has been selected. In order to take advantage of the default driver, please, ensure to install the "@nestjs/platform-express" package ($ npm install @nestjs/platform-express).*

```
async function bootstrap() {

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new UdpAdapter(app));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, unless you are using microservices, Nest *must* have an HTTP adapter (Express or Fastify) and start up an HTTP port with your server. It's part of how the websockets module and adapter gets instantiated and started.